# Regarding Matheditor - fontfamily is deprecated in MathML 3

Tags: mathml

I need to change my font family in my Matheditor but I am getting this,

> **error**: "'fontfamily' is deprecated in MathML 3, superseded by 'mathvariant'",

Can any one solve this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fontfamily is deprecated since MathML 2.0 (2003).
It is normally discouraged to set font properties within math markup.

As the standard says (MathML 2.0):

> "direct manipulation of these rendering properties by whatever means should usually be avoided".

Link to some explanation:
http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML2/chapter3.html#presm.deprecatt

font attributes are usually (if at all) set by / for the renderer. However, my experience is that tweaking fonts by whatever means is a bad idea. Default settings work best with virtually **all** renderers.